# Не передаётся значение переменной между формами

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы, в первой задана переменная s:

```
static public int s = 5;
```

Далее идёт переход в другую форму:

```
Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
        fr2.Show();
        Hide();
```

Но при попытке вызвать эту переменную в новой форме возникает ошибка:
Ошибка  2   Элемент "s" не существует в текущем контексте.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём в моём случае ошибка. Необходимо, чтобы значение переменной, введенное в первой форме было доступно и во второй.

Comment: Я понимаю, что просто так значение переменной передать нельзя. Но на форуме майкрософт нашёл этот способ:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/43b43fac-db12-47b4-874e-c97a9bb8da89/-?forum=fordesktopru

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, в котором происходит ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте передать значение поля `s` в поле новой формы `fr2`:

```
Form3 fr2 = new Form2();
fr2.s = this.s;
fr2.Show();
Hide();
```

Comment: Ошибка 2 "Alpha.Form2" не содержит определения для "s" и не был найден метод расширения "s", принимающий тип "Alpha.Form2" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: К сожалению выскакивает ошибка

Comment: @Алексей, добавьте в форму `Form3` описание поля `s`: `public int s;`

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Интересно было бы узнать, как ты в таком случае вызываешь во второй форме эту переменную.

А так в твоём случае лучше уж работать не со статичной переменной. В первой форме объяви

```
public int s = 5;
```

А потом:

```
Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
fr2.Owner = this;
fr2.Show();
Hide();
```

А во второй форме уже работать с нужной переменной:

```
(this.Owner as Form1).s
```

Answer (score 0):

Создай отдельный класс, пример :

```
class GlobalVariable
{
    public static int s { get; set; }

}
```

В первой форме присваивай ей значение. Вызывай вторую :

```
private void callAnotherForm()
{
    using (Form2 f2 = new Form2())
    {
        f2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

И там читай эту переменную, например :

```
int someVar = GlobalVariable.s;
```